# VSCode eslint and nx rules not highlighting errors in the code

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

Our VSCode suddenly start not to show the nx rules defined in the code. The ESLint output terminal is ok and outputing errors but it is not highlighting them in the code so we are realizing them so late.
here are the ss that you can understand the situation:

The error is shown in the output:

[image]

but it is not highlighted in the code:(previously it was)

[image]